# Getting the default value of a Property? (bpy.prop)

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I was wondering if we are able to get the default value used when defining a Blender property with `bpy.prop.`.

For example, having this property group:

```
class TestClass(PropertyGroup):
    # If we define this properties
    an_int_prop:IntProperty(default=-1)
    an_string_prop:StringProperty(default="hello")
```

Im wondering if I can do some kind of: `an_ind_prop.default` or similar, and get `-1` in this case.

I'm asking since I do want to offer the option to set to the default value all the properties in the class, so I plan to loop all properties in the class, access their default value, and set it again.

Having the option to access to their default value, will help me to reduce the code a lot and make it more "modular", since I wont need to add the default value for each property I add in the future.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I think I just find it!: 
test_class_object.bl_rna.properties['an_int_prop'].default